# Pasar valores de json_encode a variable en javascript

Tags: php, javascript, json

Tengo un inconveniente al tratar de pasar los valores de una variable PHP a otra en javascript. La variable en PHP es un array formulado a partir de una consulta, paso ese array por un json_encode() y lo asigno a un array en javascript:

```
var array_en_js = <?php echo json_encode($var_php) ?>;
```

Sin embargo al momento de realizarlo recibo una alerta "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;" y al analizar el codigo me aparece de la siguiente forma:

```
var array_en_js = ;
```

Ya valide que la variable de PHP tenga algun valor mediante print_r(), lo cual mostro los valores de la consulta de forma efectiva.

Los accesos a la BD estan correctos

Comment: Que valor guardas en `$var_php` ?

Comment: $var_php almacena un array de PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aviso no sé si tendrá que ver con lo que buscas solucionar pero aquí tienes que tener claro que el php solamente haya código php, y que al final de ejecutar ese php se debe de mostrar todos los datos que se quieran mostrar en el cliente (js). Ejemplo para ver si te está devolviendo bien los datos tienes que meterlo en el xampp que supongo que todo eso ya lo tendrás hecho pero pondrás en la url : localhost:8080/carpetaDondeEstaElArchivoPHP/miArchivo.php

En el que puede ver si te está devolviendo bien los datos tu php para después recogerlos con js, jquery o angularjs.

Esto serían metodos get que sería para recoger los datos que mandas desde el php

Este método es un http. Por ejemplo en js si no me equivoco es así según he mirado.

```
         function httpGetAsync(theUrl, callback)
          {
              var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
              xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
              if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
              callback(xmlHttp.responseText);
          }
              xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl, true); // true for asynchronous 
              xmlHttp.send(null);
          }
```

En jquery sería así:

```
      $.get("rutaDelArchivo/miArchivo.php", function(data, status){
                  alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
      });
```

En angularjs sería asi:

```
       var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
       app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
       $http.get("rutaDelArchivo/miArchivo.php")
           .then(function(response) {
           $scope.contenidoDeTodoElJson = response.data;
           });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

de hecho ya valide y era debido a que la tabla tenia una columna con todos sus parametros nulos, en la consulta seleccione todos los campos excepto ese y funciono. Pero tu respuesta me funciono para otro proyecto de angular 5 :D!

gracias